# When not to use volatile variable in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand the volatile variables only guarantee visibility and should not be used for atomic/compound operations. However I think I read some where that it can also be used only if one thread is updating the value (in a single operation). Is this correct ?

So if two threads are updating a volatile variable say boolean flag is this thread safe ?

Comment: It really depends on how you're using it. There are some use cases where that's true, some where it's not. Multithreading is a complex and subtle issue, so sweeping generalizations like "you should never use volatile if you have multiple writer threads" rarely hold up. Instead, you have to know what volatile gives you -- and just as importantly, what it doesn't -- and then carefully apply that to the situation at hand. It's tricky stuff, so (a) you should find a good partner to code review it with you and (b) you should consider using one of the higher-level constructs, like BlockingQueue etc.

Comment: General note: unlike some other languages, notably C and C++, in Java `volatile` actually gives some synchronization guarantees.

Comment: @yshavit I have narrowed down the scenario for you:  if two threads are updating a volatile variable say boolean flag (in a single operation e.g. set it to true or false) and without any other form of synchronizatio,n  is this thread safe ?

Comment: Again, it depends. Are they both updating it to the same value, basically as a latch? If not, is it acceptable for your application if a reading thread misses an update? Ie, if the boolean goes from true to false to true again, and my reading thread only ever sees it as true (it never saw the false), is that okay? For some usages, it is; for others, it's not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand the volatile variables only guarantee visibility and

correct

> should not be used for atomic/compound operations.

Actually all the AtomicXxxx classes use volatile. They use it in a safe manner which is the important difference. Not all operations are safe.

> I think I read some where that it can also be used only if one thread is updating the value. Is this correct ?

That is one solution.  If you have only one writer, using `volatile` is fine for that field.

Note: it is s common misconception that `volatile` confers thread safety for any operation which uses it. e.g.

```
volatile int[] a = { 0 };

a[0]++; // not thread safe even if you have only 1 writer.
```

This is because writes to `a` and only `a` are volatile. Anything which `a` points to is not also `volatile`  This is no different to `final`

```
final int[] a = { 0 };
a = null; // cannot do this
a[0] = 1; // compiles fine, is not final.
```

> I have narrowed down the scenario for you: if two threads are updating a volatile variable say boolean flag (in a single operation e.g. set it to true or false) and without any other form of synchronizatio,n is this thread safe ?

It is only safe if you have one writer, or they are both setting to the same value.  For example

```
flag = true; // ok, provided no thread sets it to false.
flag = !flag; // not ok.
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but this does not address me question

Comment: @ShivamSinha can you say in what way?

Comment: I have reedited my question to clarify: if two threads are updating a volatile variable say boolean flag (in a single operation e.g. set it to true or false) and without any other form of synchronization is this thread safe ?

Comment: @ShivamSinha I have added this to my answer ;)

Comment: _Anything which `a` points to is `volatile`_ - shouldn't that be "is not `volatile`"?

Comment: May I ask in the last example, is `x += 1` thread safe or not if I have multiple writers?

Comment: @Nier it's only thread safe for a single writer as is `x++;` AtomicInteger uses a compareAndSwap operation.

Comment: re the last bit, it's also safe if it's acceptable to miss updates. As an example off the top of my head, maybe I've got some threads that periodically check a `volatile boolean isPaused`. My thread checks and sees that it's not paused, so it does some work; a bit later, it checks again and sees it's still not paused. It probably doesn't care if between those two actions, someone paused it and then unpaused it again.

Comment: @yshavit also is you have performance metrics and you print out say a cache hit ratio and you print something like 33%, it doesn't matter if 1 in 1000 increment is lost, but having a little more performance by not making it `volatile` might be worth it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey how to do access cache hit ratios ?

Comment: @ShivamSinha accessing CPU cache hit ratios in Java is tricky, I mean software caches like in memory caches of a database.